# Multiplicity of $z=0$ on $f(z)=z\cos(z)-\sin(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I'm trying to find the multiplicity of $z=0$ on $f(z)=z\cos(z)-\sin(z)$ using complex analysis.

I'm new to complex analysis and the argument principle/Rouché's theorem so I'm not quite sure where to start. I can prove how many zero's this function has but I'm not quite sure what theorem would help me determine the multiplicity of this root, can someone point me in the right direction or provide a proof?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z\cos z -\sin z = z(1-z^2/2+z^4/24+...)-z+z^3/6-z^5/120-....)=$$

$$-z^3/3+z^5/{30} +...$$
Thus it is a zero of multiplicity  $3$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**!

Use the expansion in power series of $\cos z$ and $\sin z$. the order of $z=0$ is the order of the power series, i.e. the degree of the lowest degree term.

Comment: Your hint was excellent and I was able to piece it together before the other answer, but I marked his as the accepted one due to it being more detailed. Thank you much for the help.

Comment: Thank you for your kind appreciation. My general philosophy is  to help people find the details by themselves,  giving the starting point. It seems it worked in your case.